# PHP script sends multiple emails instead of a single one

Tags: php, html, email

I have a test web page (see below) that has a single instruction that displays a happy_face.gif image. The image source address in the test page refers to a PHP script file (see below) that returns an image and also sends an email to a single recipient address. The code listed below works fine.

However, when I use Mozilla Thunderbird or Outlook 2010 email client and insert a picture (using the email client’s image link feature) and provide the "http://www.example.com/displays_image_&_sends_email.php" as the link address, and send an email to a single email address (no CC or BCC) the following happens: The image is shown properly however in the case of Thunderbird the PHP script sends 4 emails instead of one, and when using  Outlook 2010 it sends 12 emails instead of a single one.

Please help.

Thanks,
Menachem Blasberg

http://www.example.com/Snipett_displays_image_&_sends_email.html

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/displays_image_&_sends_email.php" >
```

http://www.example.com/displays_image_&_sends_email.php

```
<?php

  // Show image in browser client.

  $logo = "http://www.example.com/happy_face.gif"; // Set image Full Path

  readfile($logo);

  // Send a test email.

    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "mblasberg@inoxel.com";
    $to = "menb@pacbell.net";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Did you analyze access logs? I think there will be several consequent requests of your sending script. It can be "features" of mail programs to request resources several times.

Answer (score 0):

the only change you need to make to send multiple emails is,put the recipient emails in the form of text seperated by comma's, and just put that text in the to address to send email to all the email ids.i.e

```
$recipients = array(
 "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
 // more emails
);
$email_to = implode(',', $recipients); // your email address
```

Comment: I probably did not explain my problem well. I do not want to send it to multiple recipients. I want to send it to a single recipient however the PHP script sends it to this recipient multiple times.